# Vim syntax explanation of 'Remember FizzBuzz?' VimGolf challenge

Tags: vim, syntax, fizzbuzz

I worked my way up (or down, if you want) to the best score of [Remember FizzBuzz?](https://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/4d1a71c0b8cb34093200010b) at VimGolf, but I have a hard time interpreting the solution:

> `33o<CR> Fizz<CR><C-H><Esc><C-V>A4k<C-H>.@.<C-U>Buzz<Esc>@.<C-V>GI0<Esc>gvg<C-A>ZZ`

I understand

> the beginning part of adding lines with "Fizz" – `33o<CR> Fizz<CR><C-H><Esc>` – and the end where the preceding line numbers are added – `<C-V>GI0<Esc>gvg<C-A>ZZ`

but I don't understand

> the middle part where the "Buzz" lines are added, i.e. `<C-V>A4k<C-H>.@.<C-U>Buzz<Esc>@.`. `4k<C-H>` moves the cursor to the correct place and the last `@.` executes the content of the `.` register, but that's as much as I can fathom.

Can someone explain the Vim magic used here? ‍♂️

Comment: well a small hint <C-U> removes all content from the position of the cursor to the beginning of the line. Like usually the deleted content is stored into the `.` register, which is later executed

Comment: Yes, although in this case, `<C-U>` does "Delete all entered characters before the cursor in the current line." (from `:help i_CTRL-U`).

Comment: I'm quite confused about what exactly `@.` vs `.` executes in this context. After running the middle part, `4k^H.@.^UBuzz` is stored in `".` (checked with `:registers`) so `@.` should execute that.

Comment: Oh, wait, I might have understood it now! Inserting `Buzz` is stored in the dot command (not sure you can check this anyway) so that's what `.` does here. The last part of `^UBuzz` is never actually run when invoking `@.` since the recursive call to `@.` comes before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The first part:**

```
33o<CR> Fizz<CR><C-H><Esc>
```

puts `Fizz` on every line that is a multiple of 3, solving the first requirement of FizzBuzz. It's done with 33 iterations of:

1. jump over an empty line,
2. put  `Fizz` on next line,
3. open an empty line,
4. leave insert mode.

33 blocks of 3 lines are added after line 1 so you get 100 lines in total and the cursor is left on line 100.

See `:help o`.

**The second part:**

```
<C-V>A4k<C-H>.@.<C-U>Buzz<Esc>
```

essentially creates a recursive macro that appends `Buzz` to lines that are a multiple of 5, instrumental in solving the second and third requirements of FizzBuzz.

In detail:

1. `<C-v>A` to start insertion on column 2, aligned with the  `Fizz`s from part 1,
2. insert `4k`,
3. do `<C-h>` to delete the `k`,
4. insert `.@.`,
5. do `<C-u>` to delete everything that was inserted on the current line,
6. insert `Buzz`,
7. leave insert mode with `<Esc>`.

That is a lot of work just to insert `Buzz` on one line but this part actually serves **three** purposes:

1. append `Buzz` to the current line (that is incidentally the last multiple of 5),
2. record that as one edit, repeatable with `.`,
3. record all that as a recursive macro in register `.`.

The macro in register `.` is:

1. `4k`, move up 4 lines,
2. `<C-h>`, move the cursor back one character,
3. `.` repeat last edit, so append `Buzz` to curent line (if there's `Fizz`, get `FizzBuzz`, if not, get `Buzz`),
4. `@.` play back macro in register `.`.

See `:help v_b_A`, `:help i_ctrl-u`, `:help .`, `help ".`, `:help @`.

**The third part:**

```
@.
```

plays back the recursive macro described above so it goes up 4 lines, then up 4 lines, and so on, solving the second and third requirements of `FizzBuzz`.

**The fourth part:**

```
<C-V>GI0<Esc>
```

inserts a `0` at the beginning of each line.

See `:help v_b_I`.

**The fifth part:**

```
gvg<C-A>
```

reselects the last visual block and then increments each `0` sequentially.

See `:help gv` and `:help v_g_ctrl-a`.

**The sixth part:**

```
ZZ
```

writes the file and quits Vim.

See `:help ZZ`.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks! One important thing to point out in **The second part** is that the edit action repeatable by the `.` command actually does all of `<C-V>A4k<C-H>.@.<C-U>Buzz<Esc>`. That is, enters blockwise Visual mode, adds `A4k<C-H>.@.` as text and then removes it with `<C-U>`, and finally inserts `Buzz` and exits back to Normal mode. This makes empty lines divided by 5 end up as `Buzz` (with a preceding space) and lines with `Fizz` as `FizzBuzz`.

Comment: I didn't think it was worth pointing out.

Comment: Ah, I think it's an interesting quirk that `<C-V>Afoo` always appends on the second column, **even on empty lines**. That's the whole reason `<C-V>A` is used in this challenge instead of `A` directly.

Comment: Not a quirk and not an accurate description either. `<C-v>` creates a 1x1 block and `A` appends to that block. The line being empty or not is irrelevant and `<C-V>Afoo` doesn't "always append on the second column".

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. I meant that if you do `<C-V>Afoo<Esc>` with the cursor on the first character of a line, `foo` will always be inserted from the second character (column 2) onward on that line, even if it was empty beforehand. To me, it's interesting that you get a preceding space character "for free" running the above-mentioned command on empty lines. With "for free" I mean that you never explicitly type a space character in the command; it's added implicitly with `<C-V>` on empty lines.

Comment: If someone wants an explanation of how the recursive execution of `@.` knows when to stop, see [this helpful VimTip](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Record_a_recursive_macro).